# Catalog category images don't appear after upload

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Catalog category images don't appear after upload.

[image]

Steps:

1. upload an image or choose one from the gallery.
2. Image preview shows.
3. I save the catalog category.
4. The image doesn't appear when the page refreshes.

   Actions taken:

   1. I have re-indexed and cleared caches.
   2. Checked for module conflicts - none.
   3. I removed all modules - no change.
   4. I upgraded site from Magento 2.3.2 -> 2.3.3 -> 2.3.4 and no change.
   5. Deleted all vendor files and reloaded with composer install/upgrade - no change.

The uploaded works and the image file for the catalog category is located in/pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/2020-04-09.jpg

Magento is NOT adding the image url to the database.

I tried manually adding the image URL to catalog_category_entity_varchar but the image never appears or becomes replaced.

Extra Notes:

My local has permission set to 777 on all files and directories. The development server has regular permissions. The local and the development server have the same issue. So not a permission problem.

There are no JavaScript errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what the Magneto file is so I can debug?

Comment: In php.ini file increase the upload size

Comment: so the upload works but the next step, move from tmp to the proper location, fails. Check filesystem permissions (you might have done that already)
Then I suggest you do an upload again with the browser developer tools turned on and look both for javascript error but also at the http response to the action call that javascript will trigger. Errors that dont appear in log can appear there.

Comment: Increasing the upload size makes no difference as there is no upload problem. The image gets uploaded and is sitting in /pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/ as I said above.

My local has permission set to 777 on all files and directories. The development server has regular permissions. The local and the development server have the same issue.

There are no JavaScript errors.

Comment: Try to load image from web browser calling direct image url. And check whether database has image entry added into it. And in template files, check urls. And I am sure you have checked log files as well (Magento and web server).

Comment: I already mention that it is NOT being added to the database.